# How can I load any web site on a frame with onload command

Tags: javascript, url, frames

I just want to open 4 pages in one page with 4 frames. but dont know how.

I want to see facebook, youtube, ebay and amazon on the same page.

Im using the onload event and try to find a code in JS to go to the page url but im clueless.

Answer (score 0):

No need for JavaScript, just set the `src` attribute if your `<iframe>` tag.

You should be aware though that many sites will bust out of these frames.  I suspect that Facebook will for sure.